# Access Level Control on a website's navigation toolbar

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a website with different web page links in the navigation toolbar. I would like that only the administrator is allowed to view the whole navigation bar while the common user will only see part of it. Do I need to employ access levels or a simple password on each page? What is the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to, you can add a login/register to your website and add admin session so normal people have access to what you defined and admin ranked people have access to the whole thing.

For that you will need php and a Mysql DataBase :)

Have a good coding !